# What's the difference between isomorphism and homeomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-topology

I think that they are similar (or same), but I am not sure.

*Can anyone explain the difference between **isomorphism** and **homeomorphism**?*

Comment: The word *isomorphism* is related to category, in which you work. For example, if you work in the category $\mathbf{Top}$ of topological spaces, the words *isomorphism* and *homeomorphism* are synonyms. But if you work in the category of smooth manifolds, isomorphism and homeomorphism are not the same things(actually all isomorphisms in such category are homeomorphisms, but converse is not true).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Homomorphism** - an algebraical term for a function preserving some algebraic operations. For a group homomorphism $\phi$ we have $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ and $\phi(1)=1$, for a ring homomorphism we have additionally $\phi(a+b) = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$ and for a vector-space homomorphism also $\phi(r\cdot a)=r\cdot\phi(a)$, where $r$ is a scalar and $a$ is a vector.

**Isomorphism** (in a narrow/algebraic sense) - a homomorphism which is 1-1 and onto. In other words: a homomorphism which has an inverse.

However, **homEomorphism** is a topological term - it is a continuous function, having a continuous inverse.

In the category theory one defines a notion of a **morphism** (specific for each category) and then an **isomorphism** is defined as a morphism having an inverse, which is also a morphism.

With such an approach, morphisms in the category of groups are group homomorphisms and isomorphisms in this category are just group isomorphisms. Similarly for rings, vector spaces etc.

In the category of topological spaces, morphisms are continuous functions, and isomorphisms are homeomorphisms.

**Extra remark:** A fundamental difference between algebra and topology is that in algebra any morphism (homomorphism) which is 1-1 and onto is an isomorphism - i.e., its inverse is a morphism. In topology it is not true: there are continuous and bijective functions whose inverses are not continuous. That's (one of the reasons) why we like compact Hausdorff topological spaces: for them inverses are always continuous, just like in algebra inverses of homomorphisms are homomorphisms.

Comment: Well, what is a topological  homomorphism? If it is a continuous function, then you're correct about the distinction between algebraic and topological morphisms. If it is a continuous (relatively) open map, then a bijective homomorphism is still an isomorphism.

Comment: @CameronBuie Do you mean a 'topological morphism'? For me, the topological category was always the category of topological spaces as objects and continuous maps as morphisms. Similarly, a morphism of topological groups is a continuous group homomorphism. Why would someone require openness/closeness?

Comment: My apologies! I actually meant to type "homomorphism," but that is nonsensical. In addition, I've discovered that I was incorrect in my impression that a monic epic morphism is always an isomorphism. My thanks for teaching me something new! (+1)

Answer (score 13):

Isomorphisms (in general) are "structure-preserving" bijections, whether they be preserving group, ring, field, topological, (partial) order, or some other sort of structure. Homeomorphisms, specifically, are topology-preserving isomorphisms.

Comment: As a side question: isomorphism are "structure-preserving" and definitionally they are bijective homomorphism. Then how should I think of a homomorphism? Is it also "structure-preserving" but in a less "preserving" manner? What does it mean when two things are homomorphic (its clear that when two things are isomorphic, they are essentially the same object with different labels)?

Comment: @MadhavNakar Homomorphism can "erase" some (or all) structure. An example is trivial homomorphism between groups that map everything to the identity element. For arbitrary group you can always construct such a map so it is meaningless to define "homomorphic"

Answer (score 1):

Isomorphism is an algebraic notion, and homeomorphism is a topological notion, so they should not be confused. The notion of homeomorphism is in connection with the notion of a continuous function (namely, a homeomorphism is a bijection between topological spaces which is continuous and whose inverse function is also continuous).

On the other hand, an isomorphism is an application which preserves algebraic structure, so it is not a topological notion. It is related to the notion of structure, i.e the notion of operations on a set.

Note that an isomorphism can be a group isomorphism, a ring isomorphism or a vector-spaces isomorphism so it's not a univocal notion.

It happens that sometimes an isomorphism can also be a homeomorphism when the topology of the spaces is considered: for instance, a linear application between finite-dimensional vector spaces which is bijective is an isomorphism, and also a homeomorphism since it is continuous and its inverse is also linear thus continuous.

But this is not the general case, for instance $]-1,1[$ is homeomorph to $\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=tan(\frac{\pi x}{2})$ but it is not an isomorphism from the algebraic point of view.

In conclusion, there is no strict inclusion of one into the other, and they are different notions.

Comment: Isomorphism is a category-theoretical notion. It may be applied to both algebraic and topological сategories.

Comment: @Oskar, I can see from your profile that you are an enthusiast of the category theory, but please take into account that the OP is probably a first year student and needs some experience with basic algebra and topology before he appreciates the abstract appeal of this theory :)